# Run .NET core grpc on docker without SSL

Tags: .net, docker, grpc

Hi I'm trying to run my gRPC .NET without an SSL but I keep getting an exception.

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.",

My GRPC code in Program.cs

```
 return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                   {
                       webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(c =>
                       {
                           c.ListenAnyIP(8060, listenOptions => listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2); 
                       });
                       
                       webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                     
                   });
```

and my client code

```
  var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
        };

        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
        var channelSSLDisabled = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8060", new GrpcChannelOptions
        {
            HttpHandler = httpHandler
        });
```

My expose ports

```
 WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 443
    EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: can you try exposing 8606 ?

Comment: I've added the port still gets the same result

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8606

Comment: can you paste your container's docker inspect result in pastebin?

Comment: I don't know any .Net, but could you set your client to not expect a server certificate. Instead could you use something similar to "insecure credentials" which other gRPC languages offer.

Comment: You need to expose the right port (8060 in this case it seems as this is where the server is listening). Also you should not use "https" when creating your channel. GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:8060", ...) - https forces an SSL connection. See instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client

Comment: I've already resolved this thanks for the answers